# How to perform SED command with Special character like && and '/' for search and Replace?

Tags: linux, shell, unix, sed

I have search string like `&& !this.peekStartsWith('//')` and want to replace with blank space .
I have tried

```
sed -i 's/&& !this.peekStartsWith('\/\/')/ /g' dist/vendor.bundle.js
```

but, getting an error like

> bash: !this.peekStartsWith: event not found

Can anyone help to work around this?

Comment: You sure that's exactly how you invoke sed? Can't reproduce such an error here

Comment: Simply executing on terminal of ubuntu 16.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do only get this to work when escaping the `!`

```
sed "s|&& \!this\.peekStartsWith('//')| |g" file
```

Example file

```
cat file
some data&& !this.peekStartsWith('//')more data
```

test

```
sed "s|&& \!this\.peekStartsWith('//')||g" file
some datamore data
sed "s|&& \!this\.peekStartsWith('//')| |g" file
some data more data
sed "s|&& \!this\.peekStartsWith('//')|***|g" file
some data***more data
```

Comment: Executing successfully, but not replacing the text with blank space :(

Comment: @AjarudinGunga Added blank space. That you should be able to figure out yourself :)

Comment: @AjarudinGunga Works fine for me.  See output example I have added.  (space and *** are added)

Comment: Ohh, it shows in the command output with replace. not actually updated on the source file. how that could be possible to direct update in the source file?

Answer (score 4):

I could reproduce the error. You need to set your `history` off as follows first, since you have `!` in your text which you are placing inside `sed` command, is causing this error.

```
set +o history
```

Now When you run `sed` command as follows, it works well.

```
echo "test && !this.peekStartsWith('//') bla" | sed "s|&& !this\.peekStartsWith('//')||g"
test  bla
```

To start `history` again you could use:

```
set -o history
```

Comment: On which version of bash?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 I didn't get your code, I want to perform find and replace

Comment: @AjarudinGunga, Yes it does that. Since your string has `!` in it so thats why you are seeing this error, once you run commands provided in answer it will not throw the errors then.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 yes it's working. I need to execute this command by code so , will it work with && ? like ```first set +o history && sed .... && set -o history```

Comment: Weird, because IIRC history substitution shouldn't happen between single quotes.

Comment: `man bash` under `"HISTORY EXPANSION - Event Designators"` reads `"!string - Refer to the most recent command preceding the current position in the history list starting with string."`

Comment: @DavidRankin-ReinstateMonica, Thank you David sir, I was about to add this :)

Comment: You are welcome -- good eye at spotting the history problem `:)`

Comment: @AjarudinGunga, No, I just tried and it doesn't work in that fashion, you could mention them command by command in your script and they should work IMHO.

Comment: @DavidRankin-ReinstateMonica there is also this [Bash: History expansion inside single quotes after a double quote inside the same line](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/390931/bash-history-expansion-inside-single-quotes-after-%20a-double-quote-inside-the-sam) can you reproduce the error in OP on your shell?

Comment: Yes, it's the `"...('//')..."` that throws a wrench into the whole "just single-quote it" thing.