# How to execute sequential base commands in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, npm-scripts

I need to run 4 bash commands sequentially in nodejs.

```
set +o history
sed -i 's/&& !this.peekStartsWith('\/\/')/ /g' dist/vendor.bundle.js
sed -i 's/&& !this.peekStartsWith('\/\/')/ /g' dist/vendor.bundle.js.map
set -o history
```

how this could be achieved? or is it possible to add in npm script?

Comment: You can either run a shell script that contains those commands or you can run them individually from within a nodejs program.  See the [child_process module](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_spawning_bat_and_cmd_files_on_windows).

Comment: What does +o do?

Comment: @slebetman To execute  SED commands with special chars `set +o history` required to set. https://stackoverflow.com/a/59133341/7566696

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To extend @melc's answer, to execute the requests sequentially, you can do:

```
const {promisify} = require('util');
const {exec} = require('child_process');
const execAsync = promisify(exec);

const sequentialExecution = async (...commands) => {
  if (commands.length === 0) {
    return 0;
  }

  const {stderr} = await execAsync(commands.shift());
  if (stderr) {
    throw stderr;
  }

  return sequentialExecution(...commands);
}

// Will execute the commands in series
sequentialExecution(
  "set +o history",
  "sed -i 's/&& !this.peekStartsWith('\/\/')/ /g' dist/vendor.bundle.js",
  "sed -i 's/&& !this.peekStartsWith('\/\/')/ /g' dist/vendor.bundle.js.map",
  "set -o history",
);
```

Or if you don't care about stdout/sterr, you can use the following one-liner:

```
const commands = [
  "set +o history",
  "sed -i 's/&& !this.peekStartsWith('\/\/')/ /g' dist/vendor.bundle.js",
  "sed -i 's/&& !this.peekStartsWith('\/\/')/ /g' dist/vendor.bundle.js.map",
  "set -o history",
];

await commands.reduce((p, c) => p.then(() => execAsync(c)), Promise.resolve());
```

Answer (score 4):

To run shell commands from node use `exec`,
https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback

Three possible approaches could be,

1. Create a bash script file containing all needed commands and then run it from node using `exec`.
2. Run each command individually from node using `exec`.
3. Use an npm package, for example one of the following (I haven't tried them)
   https://www.npmjs.com/package/shelljs
   https://www.npmjs.com/package/exec-sh

It's also possible to `promisify` `exec` (https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original) and use `async/await` instead of callbacks.
For example,

```
const {promisify} = require('util');
const {exec} = require('child_process');

const execAsync = promisify(exec);

(async () => {
  const {stdout, stderr} = await execAsync('set +o history');
...
})();
```